# VBA: Smooth data

Tags: vba, excel

I created a way in excel in which I can smooth the data via "moving average" by just changing the value of a cell (the interval) and see  the change in real time in a graph, instead of having to click in data analysis-moving average-etc every time. The problem is that the way I found slows Excel significantly since it seems to be "calculating" the moving average (or something else) every time I anything else in the same sheet. Things get worst when I have a lot of data in the same file.
This is the way I am currently doing it:
I copy the formula below in E3 and then I dragged down the same number of occupied rows in C.

```
=IF(COUNT($C$3:C3)>IntAve, AVERAGE(INDIRECT("C"&(ROW()-IntAve+1)):INDIRECT("C"&ROW())),"N/A")
```

Where Column C contains the data I want to smooth and "IntAve" is the cell that contains the number of cells to average or "interval" as is called in the moving average window.

What I wish to do with VBA, if possible, is to create a macro where it will read all occupied rows in C, read the value in the cell "IntAve" and finally perform the same calculation as above but just paste the values in Column E, so in that way the sheet is free of calculations.

When I record a macro doing the data analysis-moving average route, this is what I see

```
Application.Run "ATPVBAEN.XLAM!Moveavg", ActiveSheet.Range("$B$1:$B$74662") _
    , ActiveSheet.Range("$D:$D"), 45, False, False, False
```

But I am not sure how to utilize the macro above to do want I want.
btw 45 is the "Interval".

Now, if there is a better way to do it, I am all on board!!!!

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly:

```
Option explicit

Sub MovingAverages()

With activesheet

Dim MovingAveragePeriod as long
MovingAveragePeriod = .range("IntAve").value2

Dim LastRowInColumnC as long
LastRowInColumnC = .cells(.rows.count,"C").end(xlup).row

Dim ColumnC as range

' I assume values begin from cell C1'
Set ColumnC = .range("C1:C" & LastRowInColumnC)

With .range("E1:E" & (lastrowincolumnc - movingaverageperiod +1))

'IF YOU HAVE VALUES LOWER DOWN IN COLUMN E below the averages that you do not want to clear, comment/get rid of this line below.'
.entirecolumn.clearcontents
.formula = "=average(C1:C" & movingaverageperiod & ")" ' check the last formula in column E to make sure it has copied down correctly and refers to the correct cells in column C'
.calculate ' I think this will only calculate the newly added averages.'
.value2 = .value2 ' hopefully this replaces formulas with values'

End With

End Sub
```

1. Does that work?
2. Does it do what you want?

Sorry for bad indentation, written on mobile.

Alternatively, non-VBA approach could be to use worksheet function: OFFSET()

Answer (score 0):

As you have discovered, the INDIRECT function is volatile, which means it recalculates on every cell change, not only cells in the function range, but anywhere.

You should avoid INDIRECT unless you need to evaluate a string of TEXT. When your inputs are numerical, you can use the INDEX function instead, as that is not volatile:

`=IF(COUNT($C$3:$C3)>intAve, AVERAGE(INDEX($C:$C, ROW()-intAve+1):INDEX($C:$C, ROW())), "N/A")`